# Passing request result list into Multiprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

As the title said, i'm trying to pass a list from `requests.get()` result into Multiprocess. The script works fine except; the Multiprocess won't running even tho already triggered it using `start()`.

Here's the script i use : [Code Example](https://pastebin.com/AVA0cjyX)

What i've tried is; passing variable into multiprocess:

```
global headers, domainlist
```

It's still won't run the multiprocess, the terminal won't produce any error messages either and left me confuse as the the multiprocess trigger is fine. Sorry for the bad english...

Comment: As this is I/O bound you should consider multithreading especially as you're finding how to pass values to subprocesses too difficult. Take a look at ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures and, in particular, its *map()* functionality

Comment: Multiprocess helps me a lot in speed-up the process, can i run multithread inside a process? @AlbertWinestein

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreading is ideal for this scenario because it's I/O bound. Here's a trimmed down but fully functional variant of OP's original code that demonstrates how this could be done:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import re

HACKERTARGET = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/hostsearch'
SCHEME = 'http://'

valid_domains = []

def process(domain):
    try:
        url = f'{SCHEME}{domain}'
        print(f'Checking -> {url}')
        requests.get(url, timeout=1.0, allow_redirects=False).raise_for_status()
        valid_domains.append(url)
    except Exception as e:
        pass

domain = input('Enter domain (without scheme): ')

try:
    (r := requests.get(HACKERTARGET, params={'q': domain})).raise_for_status()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, re.findall("(.*?),", r.text))
    print(valid_domains)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```